# Search for Text inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem is: I have one div that wraps all my users list. I want to make a search box, but i don't want to use Ajax, so i started trying JQuery, for search the text inside the div and hide the another results. I've tried but i'm stucked on this:

```
    //Search Box 
$(document).on('input', "#search-weeazer", function(e){
    console.log('input ativado')
    if($(this).val().length >= 4){
        // if($('#colmeia-chat').html().indexOf($(this).val()) > -1){
        //      console.log('Found')
        // } else {
        //      console.log('Not Found')
        // }
        $('div.chat-users>div').each(function(i,div){
            if($(div).html().indexOf($(div).val()) > -1){
                console.log($(div).html() + ' found: ' + i);
            } else {
                console.log("Not Found")
            }

        });
    }


});
```

Someone know how i can do this?
Thanks!

In my HTML i have this:

```
<div class="chat-users" style="height: 400px;">
            <?php include_once('user-chat-list.php'); ?>
        </div>
```

Inside "chat-users" i have a list with all users, loaded with php

Here is more HTMl to show the structure:
https://jsfiddle.net/jdqbnz2w/

Comment: And what is your html?

Comment: @Mohammad Inside this i have a lot of another divs, loaded by PHP <div class="chat-users" style="height: 400px;">
    <?php include_once('user-chat-list.php'); ?>
   </div>

Comment: Add multiple sample content in html to solving problem

Comment: @Mohammad sorry, i don't get it

Comment: How you want to search in it If you *don't get it*?

Comment: @Mohammad i dont understood your comment

Comment: If i don't see your html, how can help you. Add more html in question. For example is your html like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8npzqwp2/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117009/discussion-between-gustavo-henrique-and-mohammad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After Question Edit**

Here is an updated JSFiddle based on the JSFiddle you included showing how to implement the search with your particular use-case:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdqbnz2w/1/)

---

**Original Answer:**

You're missing some pertinent information in your question, such as "*what does the HTML look like that comes from `user-chat-list.php`*?" And because of that it makes it hard to understand exactly how your code applies.

Nevertheless, here is a simple example upon what you have provided that you can modify that does what you are looking for. You can **run the following code snippet to see a working example:**

```js
var $searchBox = $('#search-weeazer');
var $userDivs = $('.chat-users div');

$searchBox.on('input', function() {
  var scope = this;
  if (!scope.value || scope.value == '') {
    $userDivs.show();
    return;
  }

  $userDivs.each(function(i, div) {
    var $div = $(div);
    $div.toggle($div.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(scope.value.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Search:
<input id="search-weeazer">

<p>Users:</p>
<div class="chat-users">
  <div>Tony</div>
  <div>Amber</div>
  <div>Ronald</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Your code works! But, just another little question, why this code is showing some of hidden inputs? Like: <div id="user_url" style="display:none">pedro-junqueira-12921195951</div>

Comment: Now that I can see the relevant information of how the HTML is structured from the JSFiddle you provided, it can be modified for that use-case.

Comment: @GustavoHenrique, I updated the answer to include an updated JSFiddle that shows how I did it with the HTML structure you have.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you mean. This content: `pedro-junqueira-12921195951` does not show up in the result.

Comment: It's working now! Sorry, it was my mistake! Wonderful answer

Comment: To show a message "User not found" i just put it in the "else" right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117012/discussion-between-gustavo-henrique-and-kevbot).